# Facebook graph API - stopped returning /photos

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm a (very) new dev working on a project that calls a user's photo array (comments etc) through Facebook's Graph API and all has been well, until about a week ago when the photo calls started returning NULL. All the other calls (/posts etc) are fine.

My call looks like this: userfacebookid/photos?limit=10

and then paginate from there. But... for about the last week, when I go directly to the API GUI I get nada.

I'm fearful that my constant hitting of their data while I fumble along fixing loops and learning curve coding problems has somehow blacklisted me.  Is this reasonable? How do I address it?

Thanks for any help. -M

Comment: If you *did* get blacklisted, that sounds more like something to take up with Facebook, to be honest.

Comment: Are you using the Facebook SDK? What language is your app developed in? Sounds like something that might happen if you're using an old access token.

Comment: I'm using PHP, I reset the access token (a few times), and Facebook so far has not really responded other than a dodgy "if you've be restricted  you can appeal", but the app is not 'officially' restricted.

I'm hoping for ways around the issue? Ideally not requiring a new app & dev account but that's an option.